# How can I have products if I don't have internet connection?

Tags: android, react-native, mobile

**Hi all !**

I'm working on a react native app that scans the products and adds them to the cart.

A barcode is scanned, I have the code and with this code I made a call to the backend to give me the information about the product (name, image ...)
But I realized it was a problem.

**1.** Let's say I don't have an internet connection, how can I get product data without that request ?

**2.** And how can I check if phone has internet connection ?

**Thank you !**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your backend has the data of the product, then you need to make an API call to fetch the information.

You could simply show `No Internet Connection` to the user before they scan the product to let them know the feature needs the internet connection to work.

You could use `NetInfo` package to detect internet connectivity.

```
NetInfo.isConnected.fetch().then(isConnected => {
  console.log('First, is ' + (isConnected ? 'online' : 'offline'));
});
function handleFirstConnectivityChange(isConnected) {
  console.log('Then, is ' + (isConnected ? 'online' : 'offline'));
  NetInfo.isConnected.removeEventListener(
    'connectionChange',
    handleFirstConnectivityChange
  );
}
NetInfo.isConnected.addEventListener(
  'connectionChange',
  handleFirstConnectivityChange
);
```

You could check the docs [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/netinfo.html#isconnected)

Comment: And If I don't have internet connection , where I can store all the data from backend about products ? It's a bad practice to store them in AsyncStorage?

Comment: Depends on how big is your data and how often the value changes.  You wouldn't wanna show the user old data if the data in your AsyncStorage is not updated with the backend data.

Comment: Well I thought I could always update the data when I enter the application, and maybe I can make a button to do this thing

Comment: Updating the data is a background job, what you could do is poll your backend at a certain time and check whether the version of your async storage data is different than that of backend. You could just add version to your dataset. And every time the data changes in your backend, update the version so that upon polling your app knows the data has changed. Update your data accordingly.